# New Custom Component Crashing the IDE

Tags: delphi, crash, ide, components

This is my first attempt at creating a component, I thought I would start with a very basic LED (light bulb not text), after reading a few articles I came up with the following code (which was working), I closed down the IDE (XE10.1 update2) and when trying to use the component in a new blank empty app the IDE crashes when adding the control can anybody help   :

```
unit ZaxLED;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, Controls, Forms, Graphics, ExtCtrls, Classes, math;

type
  TZaxLED = class(TGraphicControl)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FColorOn: Tcolor;
    FColorOff: Tcolor;
    Color: Tcolor;
    FStatus: Boolean;
    FOnChange: TNotifyEvent;

    procedure SetColorOn(Value: Tcolor);
    procedure SetColorOff(Value: Tcolor);

    function GetStatus: Boolean;
    procedure SetStatus(Value: Boolean);

  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure Paint; override;

  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer); override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
    property width default 17;
    property height default 17;
    property Align;
    property Anchors;
    property Constraints;
    property ColorOn: Tcolor read FColorOn write SetColorOn default clLime;
    property ColorOff: Tcolor read FColorOff write SetColorOff default clGray;

    property Status: Boolean read GetStatus write SetStatus default True;
    property OnChange: TNotifyEvent read FOnChange write FOnChange;

  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TZaxLED]);
end;

{ TZaxLED }

constructor TZaxLED.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  width := 17;
  height := 17;
  ColorOn := clLime;
  ColorOff := clGray;
  Status := False;
  Color := ColorOff;
end;

destructor TZaxLED.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TZaxLED.GetStatus: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FStatus;
end;

procedure TZaxLED.Paint;
var
  Radius, xCenter, YCenter: Integer;
begin
  if csDesigning in ComponentState then
  begin
    Canvas.Pen.Style := psDot;
    Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    Canvas.Rectangle(ClientRect);
  end;


  Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
  Radius := Floor(width / 2) - 2;
  xCenter := Floor(width / 2);
  YCenter := Floor(height / 2);
  Canvas.Ellipse(xCenter - Radius, YCenter - Radius, xCenter + Radius,
    YCenter + Radius);

end;

procedure TZaxLED.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
  if Autosize and (Align in [alNone, alCustom]) then
    inherited SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, width, height)
  else
    inherited SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight);
end;

procedure TZaxLED.SetColorOff(Value: Tcolor);
begin
  FColorOff := Value;
  if not Status then
    ColorOff := Value;
end;

procedure TZaxLED.SetColorOn(Value: Tcolor);
begin
  FColorOn := Value;
  if Status then
    ColorOn := Value;
end;

procedure TZaxLED.SetStatus(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if Value <> FStatus then
  begin
    FStatus := Value;
    if FStatus then
      Color := ColorOn
    else
      Color := ColorOff;
    if Assigned(FOnChange) then
      FOnChange(Self);
  end;
end;

end.
```

---

I have updated the code to take in comments from @Ari0nhh I think this is working but led is not changing color at design or runtime now

```
procedure TZaxLED.SetColorOff(Value: Tcolor);
begin
  FColorOff := Value;
end;

procedure TZaxLED.SetColorOn(Value: Tcolor);
begin
  FColorOn := Value;
end;
```

Comment: I rolled back your original post and added your update so both are visible without looking at the edit history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets consider this code:

```
procedure TZaxLED.SetColorOff(Value: Tcolor);
begin
  FColorOff := Value;
  if not Status then
    ColorOff := Value;
end;
```

An assignment of the property `ColorOff` will call a `SetColorOff` method. Which will again assign a `ColorOff` property. Since there is no way to break this assignment cycle, everything will end up with a stack overflow pretty fast.

Comment: I took out the If-Then line but its still crashing

Comment: Have you changed all of your properties? They all exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: between Closing the IDE (went to lunch) and starting the IDE for the new test app nothing was changed, I have uninstalled the package and re installed via the Component menu but still the same (rapidly loosing hair)

Comment: Just updated the code, seems to be working but LED not changing color in design or runtime, will I need to execute the paint function in all changes(color etc)

Comment: Because you have to redraw your control after setting the status. Call `Invalidate` for example.

Comment: I tried Invalidate and repaint at the end of the SetStatus procedure but get Control has no parent window

Answer (score 7):

I see a number of problems with your code.

- your `uses` clause needs cleanup.  Do not create dependencies on units you do not actually use.  Units that are only used by the component's internal code should be moved to the `uses` clause of the `implementation` section. The `uses` clause of the `interface` section should only refer to units that are needed to satisfy types/references directly used by your public interface.
- a `Color` data member is being declared when there is already an inherited `Color` property.  This data member is redundant and unnecessary, as its sole purpose is to carry the selected `Status` color from `SetStatus()` to `Paint()`, which is not necessary because `Paint()` can (and should) determine that color value directly.
- the `Status` property is declared with a `default` value of True, but the property is initialized to False in the constructor.
- the `ColorOn` and `ColorOff` property setters are calling themselves recursively, instead of triggering a repaint so the new state image can be shown.
- The `Status` property setter is also not triggering a repaint.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```
unit ZaxLED;

interface

uses
  Classes, Controls, Graphics;

type
  TZaxLED = class(TGraphicControl)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FColorOn: TColor;
    FColorOff: TColor;
    FStatus: Boolean;
    FOnChange: TNotifyEvent;

    procedure SetColorOn(Value: TColor);
    procedure SetColorOff(Value: TColor);
    procedure SetStatus(Value: Boolean);

  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure Paint; override;

  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    procedure SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer); override;

  published
    { Published declarations }
    property Width default 17;
    property Height default 17;
    property Align;
    property Anchors;
    property Constraints;
    property ColorOn: TColor read FColorOn write SetColorOn default clLime;
    property ColorOff: TColor read FColorOff write SetColorOff default clGray;
    property Status: Boolean read FStatus write SetStatus default False;
    property OnChange: TNotifyEvent read FOnChange write FOnChange;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses
  Math;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TZaxLED]);
end;

{ TZaxLED }

constructor TZaxLED.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FColorOn := clLime;
  FColorOff := clGray;
  FStatus := False;
  Width := 17;
  Height := 17;
end;

procedure TZaxLED.Paint;
var
  Radius, xCenter, YCenter: Integer;
begin
  if csDesigning in ComponentState then
  begin
    Canvas.Pen.Style := psDot;
    Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    Canvas.Rectangle(ClientRect);
  end;

  if FStatus then
    Canvas.Brush.Color := FColorOn
  else
    Canvas.Brush.Color := FColorOff;

  Radius := Floor(Width / 2) - 2;
  xCenter := Floor(Width / 2);
  YCenter := Floor(Height / 2);
  Canvas.Ellipse(xCenter - Radius, YCenter - Radius, xCenter + Radius, YCenter + Radius);
end;

procedure TZaxLED.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
  if AutoSize and (Align in [alNone, alCustom]) then
  begin
    AWidth := Width;
    AHeight:= Height;
  end;
  inherited SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight);
end;

procedure TZaxLED.SetColorOff(Value: TColor);
begin
  if FColorOff  <> Value then
  begin
    FColorOff := Value;
    if not FStatus then Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TZaxLED.SetColorOn(Value: TColor);
begin
  if FColorOn <> Value then
  begin
    FColorOn := Value;
    if FStatus then Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TZaxLED.SetStatus(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if Value <> FStatus then
  begin
    FStatus := Value;
    Invalidate;
    if Assigned(FOnChange) then
      FOnChange(Self);
  end;
end;

end.
```